# What to do if Xcode Archiving Utility shows wrong app for validation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive

I have two app projects on my mac. Because I was lazy to configure my project again, I just duplicated the entire project folder of my first app and renamed the project. All files in project are always relative to project itself. So it worked very good.

But today I wanted to Build & Archive an update of my first app. It all works with no complaints. But when the Archiving utility of Xcode is done, and I select my archive and click "Validate", Xcode asks for my iTunes connect credentials. Then I enter them, and in the "Please choose your application record and signing identity" dialogue Xcode offers only one Application for selection. The new (different) App only. But not the app I want to update on the App Store.

In iTunes connect I have my old app still online and clearly there is an App ID for it. But Xcode does not offer selecting this Application.

But one strange thing: The new App ID I created for my new app, has the same Bundle Seed ID as my old app which is already on the App Store. Is this a problem? Is this why Xcode offers me the wrong app to choose?

What can cause this problem? Why would Xcode archive validator not detect my app that is already on the app store and offer it for selection for archive validation?

I did not change my app or bundle ID or anything. All I did the last time was add a new app to iTunes connect but it has a different app ID / bundle ID.

Help greatly appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured out why. When I created my new app, I went to iTunes connect and added a new App ID and Application, and then clicked "**Ready to upload binary**". The mandatory step so Xcode can recognize the app and submit it.

So this was a long time ago and I totally forgot that I did this. And then I was surprised why Xcode only lists a wrong app to choose in the validator. Of course Xcode only offers what is in iTunes connect marked as "Ready for upload binary" and this was only my new app.

Now I went there and clicked "Ready to upload binary" for my new version of old app, and VOILLA. Xcode offers it.

So: Simple mistake, big headache. Hope it will be helpful for someone else in same situation.

Comment: This is a very annoying detail about the process. Why it doesn't recognize what you are trying to upload and alert you to the problem is beyond me. Instead, it gives you data that will actually throw you off the trail of the real issue. I figured this out, but checked here on stack overflow to see if anyone else had run into it. I guess I should file a bug report, or check if one already exists.

Comment: Good work! Apple fail. I hope they make this more user friendly in the future. Sometimes I want to validate another app and update another one in the store and it can be a real pain (multitasking).

Comment: Re "make this more user friendly in the future": You can now upload new builds without setting the app's status to "Waiting for binary", as long as the app has been created in iTunesConnect.