# Can't remove app waiting for upload

Tags: ios, xcode

First of, thanks for taking the time to read this. I am a true ios developer newbie, just released my first app. Now, trying to submit a second (different) app to the appstore, but that seems to go wrong. Whenever i choose validate or submit my app in Xcode, i see that it tries to do so for my previous app (created 2 different bundles IDs for that first app, being a noob and all). 
I surfed the web and found that i can delete that previous app that still has the status "Waiting for upload".

This link gives me a bit info on how to delete that broken uploaded;

[What to do if Xcode Archiving Utility shows wrong app for validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461282/what-to-do-if-xcode-archiving-utility-shows-wrong-app-for-validation)

*Please note that i have no intention on submitting that 'broken' version of my first app*.

HOWEVER, i don't seem to have any link where i can press delete, see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq73t.png

TL;DR Can't remove my app that is waiting for upload, stuck with next development app now.

Any help is very, very, very much appreciated!

Comment: Please check my answer: [how to delete an app which is waiting for upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114051/how-to-delete-an-app-which-is-waiting-for-upload/25328992#25328992)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as stated i don't have the delete button, under "links" in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT delete an app with status waiting for upload. If you upload the binary that is possible. Just call it something like "APPNAME_old"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same problem:
The only way i could solve this was by uploading an app with the same bundle-id, get that reviewed and eventually deleted.